# Autowired not working, dependency is null

Tags: spring, autowired

The project that I have is currently set up like so:

Controller:

```
package com.frclocks.district.controller;

:imports:

@Path("/districts")
@Controller
public class DistrictController {

    @Autowired
    private DistrictService districtService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<District> getDistricts() {
        return districtService.getAllDistricts();
    }
}
```

Service (Impl):

```
package com.frclocks.district.service;

:imports:

@Service("districtService")
@Transactional
public class DistrictServiceImpl implements DistrictService {

    @Autowired
    private DistrictDao districtDao;

    @Override
    public List<District> getAllDistricts() {
        return districtDao.getAllDistricts();
    }
}
```

Config:

```
package com.frclocks.config;

:imports:

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.frclocks", includeFilters=@ComponentScan.Filter(Controller.class))
public class AppConfig { }
```

The web.xml is empty as I'll be using JavaConfig instead of xml, nor do I have any spring config xml.  I have read through several tutorials online, several threads on here, and even browsed through a project at work that I'm developing with which also uses @Autowired and have reached a brick wall.  Some of the tutorials say to do something in a main class (such as here: [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06s02.html)) but the project at work doesn't do anything like that.  It has a similar AppConfig (with a few additional, not necessary annotations for me) and no xml config files.  What would I be doing wrong?  What am I missing here?  Thanks!

EDIT:  Stack trace for the null:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet 
[com.frclocks.config.FRCLocksApplication] in context with path 
[/frclocks] threw exception
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:78)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:222)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:195)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:457)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:231)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:137)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:361)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:140)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:217)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.frclocks.district.controller.DistrictController.getDistricts(DistrictController.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:511)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:402)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:366)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:361)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:368)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:340)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:313)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:441)
... 31 more
```

Comment: What error do you get exactly? Which field is null?

Comment: Sorry, should have said that:  districtService in the controller is null.

Comment: Could you also post the exact error message that you get (including stacktrace)?

Comment: Also, what's the reason for adding `includeFilters=@ComponentScan.Filter(Controller.class)`? Since `@Controller` is a meta annotation which contains `@Component`, that filter attribute is not necessary.

Comment: I added in the stack trace/error.  Since its not necessary, I will remove it.  I mostly put it in because that's what was in our other project and I was just trying a bunch of things.

Comment: Ok, you have mixed RestEasy and Spring MVC. You should decide for either of those frameworks for your REST endpoints. `@Controller` is a Spring annotation, while `@Path` is a JAX-RS annotation. Both together don't work. Currently your Controller is called through RestEasy, which doesn't know anything about your Spring configuration.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you, that was it.   I have removed the RESTEasy and exclusively used Spring and everything is working.  If you want to put that as the answer, I'll mark it as such.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed RestEasy and Spring MVC. You should decide for either of those frameworks for your REST endpoints. @Controller is a Spring annotation, while @Path is a JAX-RS annotation. Both together don't work. Currently your Controller is called through RestEasy, which doesn't know anything about your Spring configuration.